# Generate activation url

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, settings-api

For my registration I am using custom registration form.It works fine.It sends email with username and password.

What I am looking I want to generate url so that when user click it automatically complete activation .I do not want them to write username or password manually.My code
for sending email

```
                $random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
            $status = wp_create_user( $username, $random_password, $email );
            if ( is_wp_error($status) ) 
                echo "Username already exists. Please try another one.";
            else {
                $from = get_option('admin_email');
                $headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
                $subject = "Registration successful";
                $msg = "Registration successful.\nYour login details\nUsername: $username\nPassword: $random_password";
                wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers );

                echo "Please check your email for login details.";
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think similar question is answered here:

[Send user activation email when programmatically creating user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117522/send-user-activation-email-when-programmatically-creating-user)

Please have a look.

Let me know if that solves the issue.