# JSON API and notification about registration

Tags: api, json

so, I’m using JSON API, and I'm registering user with

```
localhost/api/user/register/?username=name&user_pass=pass123&email=example@example.com&nonce=0c308f17af&display_name=name&notify=yes
```

When I do that I want to user get activation email, and he’s not getting any, he’s getting info about a new account created. How can I accomplish that user first gets an activation email with link to activate its acc?

is this somehow possible?

Comment: What JSON API are you using?

Comment: I'm assuming this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/ - either way, WordPress standard behavior for user registration is not to send a verification email, so you'll probably need to code a function for this. There's a post about this here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117522/send-user-activation-email-when-programmatically-creating-user

Comment: Yes. I use that API.

Comment: How do you know that the user did not receive email?

Comment: You really asked me this question? :D

Comment: Josip, did you solve this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Set your query var `notify` to `user` (if you want to send an email to the user only) or `both` (if you want to send it to the user and the admin).

Within the plugin `controller/User.php:165` calls `wp_new_user_notification` with `$_REQUEST['notify']`.

`wp_new_user_notification` is (lucky you) a pluggable function. If you have your activation logic ready to use, you can overwrite this function and send a modified email to the user. You can overwrite it within a custom mu-plugin (must use plugin).

- Create (if not exists) a `mu-plugins` folder within `wp-content`
- Create a `pluggable.php` file. All files within `mu-plugins` behave like plugins, but are auto-loaded.
- Create your version of `wp_new_user_notification`

If you don't have an activation logic in hand, you can use the answer in the [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117522/send-user-activation-email-when-programmatically-creating-user) @Emil described in his comment.